# Android: Getting attribute colors from specific theme returns black

Tags: android, colors, attributes

I'm using this method to get the color from my attributes

**Call**

```
int color = fetchColor( getBaseContext(), R.attr.prim );
```

**Method**

```
public static int fetchColor( Context c, int id ) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes( typedValue.data, new int[]{ id } );
    int color = a.getColor( 0, 0 );
    a.recycle();
    Log.e( TAG, "COLOR: " + color );
    return color;
}
```

**Attributes**

```
<attr name="prim" format="reference|color"/>
```

**Base theme**

```
<item name="prim">@color/indigo500</item>
```

**My theme**

```
<item name="prim">@color/tealflat500</item>
```

**Result**

The color that is returned is 0 (black). Why?
I have other colors that work fine and there are no difference other than the other colors being only in greyscale (from white to black).

Edit:
The colors

```
<color name="indigo500">#3F51B5</color>

<color name="tealflat500">#37474f</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me:

**Call**

```
int color = fetchColor( getBaseContext(), R.attr.prim );
```

**Method**

```
public static int fetchColor( Context c, int id ) {
    int[] attrs = { id };
    TypedArray ta = c.obtainStyledAttributes( R.style.myTheme, attrs );
    int color = ta.getColor( 0, Color.BLACK );
    Log.e( TAG, "COLOR: " + color );
    return color;
}
```

It was from an answer to a question here on StackOverflow but I accidentally closed the tab and can't find it. But whoever came up with it, cheers mate.

Comment: Don't forget `ta.recycle();`! Very important to save memory.